# ibm mq + ssl + self signed certs

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Is it possible to use openssl to generate the necessary certs to provide self signed certs for ibm MQ broker (version 9) and client. Or can i only use ibm's internal mechanism to generate the certs (ie. runmqckm -cert ).

Please advise.
B.

Comment: Can you please tell if this is fixed and how?

Answer (score 4):

The queue manager requires a CMS format keystore that must be managed using IBM's tools.  I recommend `runmqakm` instead of `runmqckm` to manage the queue manager's keystore since `runmqakm` is compiled C and you can run through an entire script of commands before `runmqckm` is done firing up its JRE.

For anything that can use a JKS, feel free to use OpenSSL, Keytool, or anything that works with x.509 certificates.  This includes Broker's Java nodes, MQ File Transfer Edition agents, MQ client apps using native Java or JEE, and so on.